# styled-components content condition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled-components and I'm tried to add a simple condition like this:

```
const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4em;
  
  ::after {
   content: ${1 ? 'a' : 'b'};
  }
`;
```

But it doesn't do anything at all. 
when inspecting the DOM `after` wasn't there.

Tried also this:

```
...
content: ${1 && 'a'};
...
```

but still, nothing happened.

How can I use a condition and return the string that I want for the `content` css rule ?

Comment: You are missing & before after ---> &::after

Comment: still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `&` before the after seudo selector and `""` to wrap the content value. Should be:

```
const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4em;
  
  &::after {
    content: "${1 ? 'a' : 'b'}";
  }
`;
```

Comment: Yes you need to add "" here content: "${1 ? "a" : "b"}";